# C code to MIPS assembly using llvm

Tags: macos, clang, llvm, mips

I'd like translate my c codes to mips assembly using llvm. How can i do it? I'm on Mac. So llc command does not work.

Thanks

Comment: `clang -S -march=mips`?

Comment: @arrowd it gives error: unknown target CPU 'mips'

Answer (score 2):

The clang on your MacOS system won't compile for mips by default, you'll need to build your own.

You can look here: http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html for directions on building up llvm.

After that you can use clang to compile C to mips assembly by doing something like:

```
clang -target mipsel-linux-gnu foo.c -S -o -
```

which will compile the file "foo.c" to 32-bit mips assembly for the linux operating system and output it to the console.